# Multiple values in DisplayMember of DatagridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have DatagridViewComboBoxColumn bound to a datasource, i want to show "First Name" + "Last Name" in list and display member. How do i do that?

Comment: In that case You need to fill the ComboBox manually.

Comment: I have created another table adapter with concatenation query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a property to the datasource that exposes "Name".  Have the "Name" property return the "FirstName" + "LastName".

Bind to that property instead.

If the datasource is SQL, use SELECT FirstName + LastName AS 'Name' FROM table